# Share dual monitors, keyboard, and mouse between 2 Windows PCs

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, kvm-switch

I have on my desk:

1. 2 monitors
2. 1 USB keyboard
3. 1 USB mouse

all connected to a desktop PC.  All nicely setup in home office kind of room.

Somewhat often enough, I bring a laptop to that desk that I have to work on.  I want to be able to set down the laptop and switch the above mentioned IO devices to work with laptop without pulling all cables out of the desktop. All my online searches result in scrolling through lists of KVM switches, which seem to handle only one monitor or a big number of multiple devices.  The key point is that I have 2 monitors I want to use.

Could someone make a suggestion for a solution? I would like to know what options are there and, possibly, what price ranges.

Both machines are Windows 7.  Both monitors handle DVI and HDMI, but converters are fine.  Both the keyboard and mouse are USB.

Comment: Search for dual monitor KVM, there are lots out there but they are not cheap, $100 to several hundred, and you would likely need a docking station of some kind or a DisplayPort to dual DVI or HDMI adapter as well since I doubt your computer supports two HDMI or DVI connections. All in all to switch seamlessly between 2 monitors on a desktop and laptop will likely take an investment of a few hundred dollars.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I gather that both monitors have two inputs. I would suggest a set of cables for the laptop and desktop. It would require pressing two buttons one on each monitor but it would achieve the desired for or very cheap if you needed new cables / a usb video adapter. Then I would go out and get Synergy. It is more or less a software KVM for the mouse and keyboard, make your desktop the server and your laptop the client. Linus has a wonderful video here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cq4xCxmf1vQ).

That way when you bring your laptop into the scenario press two buttons Synergy should automatically connect or you could set it up to be manual (up to you) and your good to go. And as long as you don't hit the hot corners you should be able to freely switch back and forth in seconds.

*Note* *I am in no way advertising Linus, his channel, or Synergy.*

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but you may want to look at dual monitor USB graphics adapters. These sit at about $75-100, though you'd still need a (powered?) USB switch (and perhaps a hub). But you might save a bunch of money.

Answer (score 0):

This is dated - but one solution is just get two sharing devices.  Use one to control monitor A + keyboard + mouse and the other to control just monitor B.  It's not perfect, but it is probably cheaper than finding the perfect device for you.